# Find a basis of a subspace constructively

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a subspace of the standard euclidean space.  Is there a constructive method to find a basis of $V$?

Obviously, if we can realize $V$ as the image or kernel of an explicit linear transformation, then there are methods to do this, but the only way I know to find such a linear transformation requires you already have a basis (or at least a spanning set of vectors).

Comment: what do you know about $V$??

Comment: In other words, how is $V$ given? If not equations, then perhaps generators?

Comment: I'm asking for an abstract $V$ (which probably means the answer is no).  My motivation is that I'm teaching the service linear algebra course and was wondering if I could avoid a non-constructive proof of the existence of a basis.

Comment: The equality of real numbers is not constructive too. Probably, you need to replace them with computable real numbers.

Comment: My question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4857202/is-it-possible-to-prove-that-a-finitely-generated-linear-subspace-has-a-basis-co may contain an answer to your question.

Answer (score -1):

If $V$ is subset of standard Euclidian space than $V$ can have dimensions 0,1,2 or 3. 
If $V$ is an euclidean plane then it has dim $2$ and the base is any of two vectors that are nonparallel and lay on that plane.
If $V$ is a line, then you can take any vector that is parallel with that line for a base.
If $V$ is a point then dim is $0$.
In any other cases you have provide additional information about $V$, for example linear operator that describes it and from there you can get vector base.